# media query для jquery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Всем привет! Что дописать, чтобы указать, что на планшетах, телефонах (991px, 768px) эта функция не должна работать?
Вроде не сложно, но не могу найти ответ..

```js
var sidebar = new StickySidebar('.sidebar', {topSpacing: 20});
```

Comment: А почему вариант по [документации](https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/#minwidth) не подходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($(window).width() > 991) {
    var sidebar = ...
}
```